# Error when trying to get the union, intersection and difference in a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title says, I am getting an error in my code here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import random

A = random.sample(set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]), 5)

B = random.sample(set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]), 5)


print(A | B)

print(A & B)

print(A - B)
```

The error I'm getting is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'.` I have also tried `random.sample(range(10), 5)`, which still does not work.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"Is there anything I'm doing wrong?"* - you're getting an error, so: yes, clearly there is. Also the content of the error message makes it extremely clear what that mistake is: `A` and `B` are lists, not sets. You should convert to `set` *after* making the random sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as error says, function:

```
random.sample
```

returns **list** object not **set** , try convert them like this :

```
A = set(random.sample(range(1,10), 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

A = set(random.sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 5))

B = set(random.sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 5))


print(A | B)

print(A & B)

print(A - B)
```

It should produce the following output:

```
{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10}
{2, 4, 6}
{10, 5}
```